# Two times Projection triggers LINQ expression translation exception

Tags: c#, linq, automapper, projection

I'm working on application where I have to perform the projection 2 times
1- Between EfModel and DomainModel
2-Between DomainModel and DTO

I'd like to keep the process as IQueryable all the way from the request to response, so I perfomed the following steps

1-
In Interface layer where my graphql query lands:

```
public async Task<IQueryable<BoxDto>> Boxes ([Service] IBoxService boxService, [Service] IMapper mapper)
 {
     //GetAll as you will see in the next step returns a DomainModel _Box_
     //We project it here to a DTO _Exactly here the exception being triggered
     return (await boxService.GetAll()).ProjectTo<BoxDto>(mapper.ConfigurationProvider);
 }
```

Application layer

```
public async Task<IQueryable<Box>> GetAll()
   {
       return await _boxRepository.GetAll();
   }
```

Then the in the repository

```
    public async Task<IQueryable<Box>> GetAll()
    {
       //Here we project from the DBModel _Kisten_ to Box  works smoothly although it's more complex as from DomainModel to DTO
        return _dbContext.Kisten.AsNoTracking().ProjectTo<Box>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider);
    }
```

If I replace the `<IQueryable<BoxDto>>` with `<IQueryable<Box>>`  everything works well even with complex and nested queries, the problem is with the second projection
it worth to share that
-The BoxDTO and Box are identical, the types are of course different but the properties has the same names
-The query takes in normal case 700 ms if I return a DomainModel, while it takes 35 Seconds until the exceptions shows up
-I've tried the MaxDepth(1) as I had a doubt of circular references but with no difference

Comment: Why incorporate AutoMapper in your IQueryable? Just return the db set AsQueryable() and then map after you get your list.

Comment: we're following DDD the interface layer where the DTO is defined shouldn't know about the infrastructure layer where the DBSet is defined, the integration between them takes place in the application layer. thanks :)

Comment: If you're doing DDD you have your layers messed up! :)

Comment: I'd appreciate a comment that would help either in mapping or DDD ;)

Answer (score 0):

From the [AutoMapper’s documentation](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html#queryable-extensions):

> `ProjectTo` must be the last call in the chain. ORMs work with entities, not DTOs. So apply any filtering and sorting on entities and, as the last step, project to DTOs.

So this is kind of expected.

Comment: Thanks for the tipp, I actually do. In the case above there're no filters at all, just 2 times simple projection without flattening or advanced stuff